# Clearcase: Move a file from base VOB to a UCM VOB

Tags: clearcase

How would I go about moving elements between base and a UCM VOB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible from Base To UCM..not in a clean way anyways

Comment: How about from remote base CC to local base CC? And *then* declare it as a UCM component?

Answer (score 1):

First: a base VOB can also be an UCM VOB (i.e. it can have non-UCM directories, and UCM component)

When I define a new component, I always do it in a special branch, in order to allow developers to go on and modifying version in their legacy non-UCM views, while reorganizing the directories and defining an UCM component:
Since the root directory of that UCM component is in a special branch, nobody sees anything until they define their own UCM view referencing that component.

The key factor you need to be aware of is that, once a UCM component is defined, you won't be able to move its elements *outside* said component:

- you cannot move them within the same VOB as the one where you define your UCM component( I am speaking here of a component define within the VOB, not of a "VOB component" where the all VOB is a component!)
- you cannot move them from the component to another VOB

One scenario I am aware of is the necessity too split an UCM component in two, relocating some of its code elsewhere (either in the same VOB or in another).
In that case, the only solution is to list the baseline of the source components, and **`clearfsimport`** the part you need to another directory elsewhere.
See the "[clearfsimport to new stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833544/clearfsimport-to-new-stream/1834069#1834069)" SO question for more on that `clearfsimport` process)

If you add some precisions about your current scenario, I will complete this answer with possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for information! The scenario we have is that there are some elements within a base clearcase vob (stored overseas) that we want to move to a local clearcase server. Since we're using mostly UCM that's probably what we want to use. Keeping the history is obviously important in the migration. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible for my scenario